# how to save location of multiple draggable jquery elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
$(function() {
  var xpos = $(`#${currentid}`).position();
  console.log(xpos.top);
  var sPositions = localStorage.positions || "{}",
    positions = JSON.parse(sPositions);
  $.each(positions, function(id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos);
    console.log("it saves");
  })
  $(`#${currentid}`).draggable({
    containment: "#body1",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      positions[this.id] = ui.position;
      localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions);
      console.log("it loads");
    }
  });
});
```

In this, I have to traverse to each element but it still not working please help

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS.

Comment: https://del.dog/javascript123
https://del.dog/myiehtml123
https://del.dog/mycss123 here all all html,css,and js files plz excuse bad coding practices i am coding first time